# Heuristic consistency definition for undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, a-star, heuristics

In the A* path search algorithm the general definition for an consistent heuristic is *h(m)<=h(n)+d(m,n)* for any edge *(m,n)*.

Is this true also for an undirected graph? In an undirected graph *(m,n)=(n,m)* and *d(m,n)=d(n,m)* and will also be true that *h(n)<=h(m)+d(n,m)*, this means that *h(n)=h(m)* for all *m* and *n*. But this seams to be absurd.

Where am I doing wrong? Maybe in an undirected graph the consistency of a heuristic is *h(m)<=h(n)+d(m,n)* for *m* successor of *n*?

Comment: Did my answer help answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, your reasoning is correct but your maths are not.

Yes, for an undirected graph you get two inequalities:

*h(m) <= h(n) + d(m, n)*

*h(n) <= h(m) + d(m, n)*

This does not imply that *h(n) = h(m)*. If you flip the *d* term over in the latter, equation, you get

*h(n) - d(m, n) <= h(m)*

so you get

*h(n) - d(m, n) <= h(n) + d(m, n)*

so

*-d(m, n) <= d(m, n)*.

The only way in which this implies *h(n) = h(m)* is if *d(m, n) = 0*.